# Can this wavlength expression be simplified further?

Tags: waves, interference, diffraction

I am supposed to be expressing the wavelength of light that produces 1st order fringe on the viewing screen, given that the diffraction grating has **spacing d** and the fringes are viewed on a screen located at a **distance L** away. 
What I have now:
$\lambda = \frac{d\sin \theta_m}{m} = d\sin \theta_1 = d\sin(\arctan (\frac{y_m}{L}))$ where $y_m$ is the location of bright fringe 1 on the screen. 
Is that possible to just express this in terms of d and L?

Comment: L and $y_m$ form the sides of a right triangle, namely the adjacent side and opposite side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this sketch [from Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mehrfachspalt-Numerisch.png#/media/File:Mehrfachspalt-Numerisch.png) that shows the intensity of the diffracted light.

[image: diffraction pattern]

Now imagine placing a vertical screen somewhere to the right of the grating. The horizontal distance from the screen to the grating would be $L$, and the vertical distance of a diffraction peak to the center of the grating would be  your $y_m$. You can see that *for the same wavelength and grating*, if you move the screen closer or further away, the positions of the peaks $y_m$ will change. So you see that in order to calculate the wavelength, you must know *both*, the distance $L$ and the position of the peak $y_m$ (in addition to $d$). Knowing $L$ and $d$ alone does not contain enough information to determine $\lambda$.